# Theme change does not work after navigating back from activity in forced landcape

Tags: android, kotlin

Context: I am working on a navigation app which has a map on it's main activity. One of the activities you can navigate to is a head up display activity which is in forced landscape mode. I cannot restart the main activity since it's too consuming for the map to be restarted. The app also has an automated mode for switching between light and dark mode (eg. when entering a tunnel the app switches to dark mode and when exiting the tunnel it switches back to light theme).As such I must handle configuration changes myself. However I encountered somewhat of a bug so I wanted o test things out in a simple project.

In my simple project I have a main activity with 2 buttons and a "landscaped" activity. The first button changes the theme and the second one navigates the user to the landscaped activity. When the phone is in dark mode and the app starts with default light mode clicking the navigation button will lead to the second activity. Here is the weird part. If after navigating back the phone is in a different orientation than it was when navigation to the landscaped activity 2 consecutive configuration changes will be triggered: first one with the phone's theme and the second one with the theme set programmatically, otherwise no configuration changes will be triggered. In both scenarios the first button won't work now unless another orientation change is done to the phone.

This behavior is causing bugs to occur in my app. Am I doing something wrong? Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.themetest

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    lateinit var btn: MaterialButton
    lateinit var themeBtn: MaterialButton
    lateinit var r: ConstraintLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btn = findViewById(R.id.hello_btn)
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, LandscapedActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        themeBtn = findViewById(R.id.theme_btn)
        themeBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (isNightThemeOn())
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            else
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        }

        r = findViewById(R.id.main_root)
    }

    fun isNightThemeOn(): Boolean =
        (resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration)
    {
        val a = isNightThemeOn()
        btn.setBackgroundColor(
            if (isNightThemeOn())
                Color.WHITE
            else
                Color.BLACK
        )
        btn.setText(if (isNightThemeOn()) "DARK THEME" else "LIGHT THEME")
        r.setBackgroundColor(
            if (isNightThemeOn())
                Color.BLACK
            else
                Color.WHITE
        )
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    }
}
```

here is main activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_root"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/theme_btn"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="CHANGE THEME!"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/hello_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/hello_btn"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Light Theme!"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/theme_btn" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GEM"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".LandscapedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|fontScale|uiMode"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I literally have no idea what to do next.